In Javascript are there non functional reasons to call removeEventHandler?
Suppose I added an event listener to some element on the DOM,
Will leaving it attached when the DOM element is destroyed cause some sort of memory leak even assuming that the JavaScript engine is doing its work properly / to the best of its ability ?
So basically - apart from the functional reasons of "I don't want this event handler to run again" Do I need to call removeEventHandler?
It was pointed that this might be similar to Does Javascript remove event handlers of deleted DOM elements?
but with all due respect - that Q is from 2011... and the answer basically says something like "you should remove then just in case" is based on an article from 2005...
The quality of browsers has changed significantly since than, but still I see comments about having to call remove removeEventHandler (in my case I actually saw a suggestion to do this in a vuejs component's onunmount() but I think this is not specific to vuejs).
I would like a current answer that would tell me if this is still a valid recommendation or is it just in case someone will try to run my code in IE8 ....

Even though the element will be gone, the JS references won't likely have been removed. So yeah I think it could cause a memory leak (albeit a small one)

@evolutionxbox What do you mean when you say "the JS references won't likely have been removed"? References to what? From where? And what are you basing that statement on?

Like with other reference cycles, there’s no memory leak (in non-buggy browsers), but I actually don’t know how it might affect GC behavior.
